# SWF file is not displaying in browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, flash

We have a flex project which called from browser by using a swf file. After flash update the swf file is disabled.
Here are the list of flash versions and browsers that we used in windows 7 OS.

- Installed Firefox 56.0 - NPAPI 25.0.0.170 version in Firefox . -
  Issue exist
- Installed Firefox 56.0 - NPAPI 25.0.0.127 version in Firefox . -
  Working Fine
- Installed Firefox 56.0 - NPAPI 24.0.0.221 version in Firefox . -
  Working Fine
- Installed Firefox 56.0 - NPAPI 24.0.0.194 version in Firefox . -
  Issue exist.

---

- Installed Chrome 61.0.3163.100 - PPAPI 25.0.0.170 version . - Issue
  exist
- Installed Chrome 61.0.3163.100 - PPAPI 25.0.0.127 version . - Issue
  exist

When we try to run the swf file via web application it checks the air run time has installed or not and gives the status as "Available".
[air status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGSNq.png)

We have installed adobe air and current version is 27.0.0.124.
[air version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Hzt.png)

Since the application is a web distribution is that enough to go only with air installation?

Answer (score 0):

AIR is a desktop application, not a browser plugin:

> Adobe® AIR® is a multi-operating system, multi-screen runtime that allows you to leverage your web development skills to build and deploy rich Internet applications (RIAs) to the desktop and mobile devices. Desktop, television, and mobile AIR applications can be built with ActionScript 3.0 using Adobe® Flex and Adobe® Flash® (SWF based). Desktop AIR applications can also be built with HTML, JavaScript®, and Ajax (HTML based).

Browser support for SWFs has changed recently:

> Each of the major browsers has now implemented a feature where Adobe Flash content does not run by default, but each of the browsers has implemented this feature and the user interface in slightly different ways.

**References**

- [About Adobe AIR](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fc4.html)
- [Flash Activation: Browser Comparison - Plugins | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Plugins/Flash_Activation:_Browser_Comparison)
- [Flash Tester](https://www.flashtester.org/)